# Send objects to C# code from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

How can I send some object, say a JSON object, from JavaScript to my C# code for windows phone app?

I know of `window.external.notify` function. But this can send only `string` as a single parameters.

What if I want to send two different parameters?

Comment: Hey stranger. If you could have answered my question before downvoting it, that would have been fine for me. But since u didn't, may I know reason behind this?

Comment: Why not just delete the question and get your rep back?

Answer (score 0):

To try answer your json question, why not serialize your object into a json string.  I like to use NewtonSoft.Json to do that.  Google for it or pull down with nuget. It is supported for Windows phone

Comment: Could be the reason. I am trying on a remote server. But how will the answer differ if I say device.

Comment: Might be an architectural problem then. So the site pushes data to the device? Might be difficult to scale as what happens when you have thousands of devices. You can look at SignalR of your server is asp. Net. Not sure how it relates to phones tho. Else look at having your app pull the data from a service. Or look at implementing push notifications sent to your device to tell it to pull some days

Comment: Yes. There are JavaScript functions that connect to other server to get data and then returns them. I don't know how to recieve them on client side c# code

Comment: Have a look at msdn for httpClient. There are great examples of accessing a Rest service